# Popup appears as modal on Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift2

I am trying to make a popup in Swift 2.2. But every time I get a modal in place of popup. I am using iPhone 6/iOS 9. I have similar code in objective C, which works just fine. Please could you advise whats wrong in below code.

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let popupList = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PopupList") as UIViewController!
    popupList.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    popupList.preferredContentSize   = CGSizeMake(300, 200)

    let popoverPresentationViewController = popupList.popoverPresentationController

    popoverPresentationViewController!.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any
    popoverPresentationViewController!.delegate = self
    popoverPresentationViewController!.sourceView = self.view
    popoverPresentationViewController!.sourceRect = sender.bounds
    presentViewController(popupList, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popover are supposed to be working as popover only on iPads. You can refer [UIPopoverController Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/index.html) to verify this.  If used in iPhones they behave as a model presentation. You can use library like [WYPopoverController](https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController) to achieve popovers for iPhone.

**Edit**

When using `UIPopoverPresentationController` we should implement its delegate method. The delegate method of `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` can be used as below.

```
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle{
   return .None
}
```

Returning none make sure that we do not want full-screen popovers.

Comment: Manjul, please check the link you have shared. Its deprecated in iOS 9. UIPopoverController is deprecated. With iOS 8, UIPopoverPresentationController is the new thing. Also as I mentioned in my question, I have the similar code for objective C and it works very well on iPhone.

Comment: Sorry for the link on UIPopoverController. I did went through UIPopoverPresentationController and tried your code and did manage to generate pop over for iPhone. I added a delegate method of  UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate. I will add code for you.

Comment: Glad i could be of help.